# Autofocus on IonInput when Modal Is Shown using useIonModal

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks, ionic-react

I've been looking at https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/managing-focus#overlays and I haven't got it to work when working with modals created with `useIonModal`, or am I doing it wrong?

In my parent component i have

```
  const modalUsernameInput = useRef<HTMLIonInputElement>();
  const [presentAddUserModal, dismissAddUserModal] = useIonModal(
    UserViewModelModal,
    {
      dismiss: (data, role) => dismissAddUserModal(data, role),
      usernameInput: modalUsernameInput
    } as UserViewModelModalProps
  );
```

The part where I present the modal is

```
<IonFabButton
            onClick={() => {
              presentAddUserModal({
                cssClass: "popup-modal",
                onDidPresent: (ev) => {
                  console.log(modalUsernameInput.current);
                  modalUsernameInput.current?.focus();
                }
              });
            }}
          >
            <IonIcon icon={add} />
          </IonFabButton>
```

and then `UserViewModelModal` looks like

```
export interface UserViewModelModalProps extends ModalProps<AddUserViewModel> {
  usernameInput?: React.RefObject<HTMLIonInputElement>;
}

export const UserViewModelModal: React.FC<UserViewModelModalProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper ion-padding">
      <h1>Add User</h1>
      <IonInput
        label="Username"
        labelPlacement="fixed"
        ref={props.usernameInput}
      />
      <IonInput label="Password" labelPlacement="fixed" type="password" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Why is it not focusing on the input? What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it supposed to be `setFocus()` instead of `focus()`.